# reverse url django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-url-reverse

small problem of Django and its reverse url,
I try to have a link from a model to another model in the same admin:app
I have this function to run `reverse('admin:jobs_xml_jobboardexterne')`

I run from this page `admin/jobs_xml/countjobboarderrors/`
and I get an error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf00J.png
here the code was make the call :

```
class CountJobBoardErrorsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("have_error_job_board", "have_not_error_job_board", "total_job_board")

    def have_error_job_board(self, obj):
        url = reverse('admin:jobs_xml_jobboardexterne')
        return mark_safe(f'<a href={url}>{JobBoardExterne.objects.count()}</a>')
```

ok, so Django can't find my link,
in my settings.py I have the application noted

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...,
  'jobs_xml',
  ...
]
```

my project urls.py also

```
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = [
  ...,
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

an idea ? I can't find the error.
thank you for your help :)

SOLUTION >>> I was needed to add the verbe
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'change_list' to the end.

Try:

```py
reverse('admin:jobs_xml_jobboardexterne_changelist')
```

Or (if `jobboardexternes` is plural)

```py
reverse('admin:jobs_xml_jobboardexternes_changelist')
```

Comment: Oh yes, I just needed to add the "verbe"